# Sum of non-negative elements in array

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

Given an array of $A=[1,2,4, -5, -10, 34]$ and $A_{size} = 6$,
how can I write mathematically the sum only of non-negative values? 
For example $S$ like $\sum_{i=1}^n (sign(A_i)\times A_i)$ but mathematically in formula ?

Comment: What about $\sum_{A_i \geq 0} A_i$?

Comment: Do you want the sum of the non negative values (that would be $1+2+4+34$ in your example, or the sum of the absolute values (which is what your expression - probably - gives, in your example that would be $1+2+4+5+10+34$)?

Comment: only non negative so 1,2,4,34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it as:

$$S^-=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (A_i - |A_i|)}{2}$$
$$S^+=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (A_i + |A_i|)}{2}$$

where $S^-$ is sum of negative elements and $S^+$ is sum of all positive elements.

Comment: This is what I was needed, thanks.

Comment: Possibly clearer as $\sum_i \min(A_i,0)$ and $\sum_i \max(A_i,0)$.